# Angular forms with ng-switch

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, ng-switch

I'm trying to get a form object from the scope of a controller when I get a name to de form.
It work fine, but if I create the form with a ng-switch, the form never shows in the scope.

*the view*

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-switch on="type">
      <form name="theForm" ng-switch-when="1">
        <label>Form 1</label>
        <input type="text"/>
      </form>
      <form name="theForm" ng-switch-when="2">
        <label>Form 2</label>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="text"/>
      </form>

    </div>

    <button ng-click="showScope()">Show scope</button>
</body>
```

*the controller*

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.type = 1;

  $scope.showScope = function(){
    console.log($scope);
  };
});
```

If I remove the ng-switch I can see the property "theForm" from the $scope as the form obj.

Any idea how to do it. I don't want to have the two forms with different names and use ng-show.

Here is the example "not-working"
http://plnkr.co/edit/CnfLb6?p=preview

Comment: thx. spent an hour on this. the symptom I got was that $valid and $dirty became unavailable to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `ngSwitch` creates new scope. (If you look at the `$$childHead` value of the scope that get's `console.log`'d, you can see `theForm` inside it. This is the `ngSwitch` scope).

If the form will always be the same name, you can simply put the `ngSwitch`es inside the form:

```html
<form name="theForm">
  <div ng-switch on="type">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">
      <label>Form 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
      <label>Form 2</label>
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot more than I expected with your answer.

Comment: Instead of using `ng-switch on` as a attribute, we can use it as a separate tag to make more readable. Ex: `<ng-switch on="ur swich condition">...</ng-switch>`

Comment: @Abilash True, but if you care about IE 8 and below, be sure to use `document.createElement` as per [the Internet Explorer Compatability guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: @Brandon I think this works fine on IE8 as well. I've used it in my application and fortunately there were no problems until today.